# read form authentication cookie between websites on same server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have two websites hosted on same windows server.

1) Asp.net web application Framework 4.0 (abc.com/site1)

2) MVC application Framework 4.5.2 (abc.com/site2)

Now I want to implement SSO approach between these sites. i.e when user logs into asp.net application then its gets redirected to MVC application and there I'll check form auth cookie.

But I am having issue reading form auth cookie.

1. When user logs in to asp.net application, I am using below code for form authentication

```
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), false);
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket1 =
            new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                 1,                                   // version
                 txtUserName.Text.Trim(),   // get username  from the form
                 DateTime.Now,                        // issue time is now
                 DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),         // expires in 30 minutes
                 false,     // cookie is not persistent
                 ""                              // role assignment is stored
            // in userData
                 );
        HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(
          FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
          FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket1));
        cookie1.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);
```

and web.config code is as below

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="Form.AUTH" loginUrl="~/Home.aspx" protection="All" path="/" requireSSL="true" domain="abc.com" cookieless="UseCookies" />
    </authentication>
    <machineKey validationKey="4B616C4E8BE5E18C3A1650939E88F3B0ED1AFC692919D7937DA68BBC552F04027DCF8BD31125E5E69094E1A4BA96731067BB57F0D3C34B63B9B03123703CD01A" decryptionKey="EC095D7743D3368F22FB7F482D9F41AA911922EC753515BB"   validation="HMACSHA384"  compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2" />
```

Now for 2nd application(MVC) in order to read same cookie, Web.config changes as below

```
<machineKey validationKey="4B616C4E8BE5E18C3A1650939E88F3B0ED1AFC692919D7937DA68BBC552F04027DCF8BD31125E5E69094E1A4BA96731067BB57F0D3C34B63B9B03123703CD01A" decryptionKey="EC095D7743D3368F22FB7F482D9F41AA911922EC753515BB"   validation="HMACSHA384"  compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="account/" name="Form.AUTH" protection="All" path="/"  domain="abc.com" requireSSL="true" cookieless="UseCookies"></forms>
    </authentication>
```

and to read same cookie in MVC app, code is as below. I have written in Global.asax file

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    logClass.logger.Info("Request is authencated  -- If");
                }
                else
                {
                    logClass.logger.Info("Request is authencated   -- else");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                logClass.logger.Info("Request is authencated -- Error");
            }

            try
            {
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    logClass.logger.Info("User.Identity.IsAuthenticated -- If");
                }
                else
                {
                    logClass.logger.Info("User.Identity.IsAuthenticated -- else");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                logClass.logger.Info("User.Identity.IsAuthenticated -- Error");
            }


            HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Form.AUTH"];
            string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
            logClass.logger.Info(myCookies);
            logClass.logger.Info(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
            try
            {

                logClass.logger.Info(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Form.AUTH"].Value);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                logClass.logger.Info("Error value");
            }
            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                logClass.logger.Info(authCookie.Value);
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                if (authTicket.UserData == "OAuth") return;
                CustomPrincipalSerializedModel serializeModel =
                  serializer.Deserialize<CustomPrincipalSerializedModel>(authTicket.UserData);
                CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
                //newUser.Id = serializeModel.Id;
                newUser.FirstName = serializeModel.FirstName;
                newUser.LastName = serializeModel.LastName;
                HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
            }
        }
```

Now problem is that When user logs into asp.net web application user is authenticated and form authentication cookie is created but when MVC app is opened as you can see neither of below code works

```
Request.IsAuthenticated  : false
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated   : false

 HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Form.AUTH"];  // its null
                string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
                logClass.logger.Info(myCookies);  // no Form.AUTH cookie in it
                logClass.logger.Info(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
```

Comment: Is the cookie being sent as part of the request to MVC app?

Comment: i didn't get your question but after authentication.. I am just redirecting to site2 using Response.Redirect("site2url");

Comment: So after redirect, when the browser makes request to Site2, have you inspected the request headers to see that cookie is being sent as part of the request? I'm asking this to make sure if the cookie is being sent and the problem is with decryption.

Comment: Yes cookie is there in request header after its redirected to site2 page.. but if i check through code 'Request.Cookies.AllKeys' .. its missing in this